# how to resolve GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline error using javafx 17

Tags: java, linux, javafx, netbeans

I 'm trying to compile a project using java11 and javafx 17 on rocky Linux

I followed the javaFX (non modular) guide for Eclipse and it works fine.

I did the same with netBeans (12.6) and its a semi success, project runs perfectly when launched directly from Netbeans. But after compiling the project without error it fails at execution displaying this :

```
mars 22, 2023 11:30:05 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
AVERTISSEMENT: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @57116b8b'
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_es2 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1870)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:166)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:63)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_sw in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1870)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:166)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:43)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:254)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:266)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:230)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:278)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:230)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Apparently first warning could be ignored, the thing i don't undertand is why application runs correctly under eclipse and netbeans and not after compilation , what is the difference  and what is missing ?

reading next lines, seems that prism_es2 and prism_sw where missing at expected location

actually I didn't find those files but i saw comparable files in the javafx directory

```
/home/userdev/javafx-sdk-17.0.6/lib/libprism_es2.so
/home/userdev/javafx-sdk-17.0.6/lib/libprism_sw.so
```

why it's seems to use those files in eclipse and netbeans but not with generated jar ,
how can I solve this ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your "generated jar" is incorrect.  Probably it doesn't include native code required to use a JavaFX application.  You won't get much assistance without providing reproducible steps on how you generated the jar and how you executed it.  Probably a "generated jar' is an incorrect or suboptimal approach.  For packaging info see the [javafx tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx).  Also, I don't suggest mixing Swing and JavaFX unless you really need to.

Comment: Yes it an old project hard to maintain using swing, i hope to move it to pure javafx gradually . _      Jar is generated by netbeans and included all javafx jar and works from netbeans but once this same project compiled with netbeans its different . this Prism error seems to be a repetitive error with javafx but consulting all forums about i arrived at maximum I can and none was this same context

Comment: *"Jar is generated by netbeans and included all javafx jar"* -> though you may be able to get such a setup to work, as will be noted in articles linked from the referenced JavaFX tag wiki, such a setup is not supported.  Modern JavaFX versions assume JavaFX modules are on the module path, which is not possible if you include JavaFX libraries in a single jar file.